# I keep getting a circular reference when using ChatGPT with LangChain

Tags: python, pycharm, openai-api, langchain

I took a couple of code samples, added a little Streamlit markup, and blew up my project.  Everything processes just fine until you ask this app a question - then I get a circular reference error.  Can somebody please take a look and let me know what I am doing wrong?

Error:

```
An error occurred: Circular reference detected on line <traceback object at 0x0000027FDC728440>

Error in tracing queue

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\venv\Lib\site-packages\langsmith\client.py", line 4112, in     _tracing_thread_handle_batch

client.batch_ingest_runs(create=create, update=update, pre_sampled=True)

  File "\venv\Lib\site-packages\langsmith\client.py", line 1220, in batch_ingest_runs
    "post": [_dumps_json(run) for run in raw_body["post"]],
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "\venv\Lib\site-packages\langsmith\client.py", line 236, in _dumps_json
    return _dumps_json_single(obj, functools.partial(_serialize_json, depth=depth))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "\venv\Lib\site-packages\langsmith\client.py", line 211, in _dumps_json_single
    return orjson.dumps(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

***UPDATE***
I re-wrote the code to break it into menu options in case it was re-running something recursively somehow. It did not help...

```js
import os
import streamlit as st  # used to create our UI frontend
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI # used for GPT3.5/4 model
from langchain_community.document_loaders import TextLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
from langchain_community.document_loaders import YoutubeLoader
from langchain_community.callbacks import get_openai_callback

def init_page():
    st.set_page_config(
        page_title="The Moss Masher",
        page_icon=":dog:"
    )
    st.sidebar.title("Menu")
    st.sidebar.image("./FullLogo.png", width=300, use_column_width="always")
    st.session_state.costs = []

def select_model(model, aiTemp):

    if model == "GPT-3.5":
        st.session_state.model_name = "gpt-3.5-turbo"
        st.session_state.max_token = 16385
    elif model == "GPT-3.5-16k":
        st.session_state.model_name = "gpt-3.5-turbo-16k"
        st.session_state.max_token = 16385
    else:
        st.session_state.model_name = "gpt-4"
        st.session_state.max_token = 8192

    # 300: The number of tokens for instructions outside the main text
    return ChatOpenAI(temperature=aiTemp, model_name=st.session_state.model_name)

def init_messages():
    clear_button = st.sidebar.button("Clear Conversation", key="clear")
    if clear_button or "messages" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.messages = []
        st.session_state.costs = []

def clear_history():
    if'history' in st.session_state:
        del st.session_state['history']

def create_login_page():
    st.title(":football: :green[The Moss Masher] :dog:")
    st.header("Mash your long documents and videos into easy answers!")
    container = st.container()
    with container:
        with st.form(key="frmOptions", clear_on_submit=True):
            st.markdown("To use this app, please provided an OpenAI key")
            st.markdown(
                "First, create an OpenAI account or sign in: "
                "https://platform.openai.com/signup and then go to the API key page, "
                "https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys, and create new secret key.")
            userEnteredCode = st.text_input("Please enter your API Key:")
            submit_button = st.form_submit_button(label='Authenticate My Key')
            st.session_state["holdMe"] = os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]
    if submit_button and userEnteredCode and userEnteredCode != "":
        # We need to set our environmental variable
        if os.environ["MOSS_MASHER"] != userEnteredCode:
            os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = userEnteredCode
        else:
            os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = st.session_state["holdMe"]
        st.markdown("Got your code!  Now click on Upload a PDF or Enter Youtube Video!")
def create_pdf_page():
    st.title(":football: :green[The Moss Masher] :dog:")
    st.header("Mash your long documents and videos into easy answers!")
    container = st.container()

    with container:
        uploaded_file = st.file_uploader('Select your file and click Add File:', type=['pdf', 'docx', 'txt'])
        add_file = st.button('Add File', on_click=clear_history)

    if uploaded_file and add_file:
        with st.spinner('Mashing your file into vectors, this may take a while...'):
            bytes_data = uploaded_file.read()
            file_name = os.path.join('./', uploaded_file.name)
            with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(bytes_data)

            name, extension = os.path.splitext(file_name)
            if extension == '.pdf':
                from langchain_community.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
                loader = PyPDFLoader(file_name)
            elif extension == '.docx':
                from langchain_community.document_loaders import Docx2txtLoader
                loader = Docx2txtLoader(file_name)
            elif extension == '.txt':
                from langchain_community.document_loaders import TextLoader
                loader = TextLoader(file_name)

            documents = loader.load()

            text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200)
            chunks = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

            embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
            vector_store = Chroma.from_documents(chunks, embeddings)

            os.remove(file_name)
            st.session_state["retriever"] = vector_store.as_retriever()
            st.write("PDF mashed!  Click on Ask Questions!")
def create_youtube_page():
    st.title(":football: :green[The Moss Masher] :dog:")
    st.header("Mash your long documents and videos into easy answers!")
    container = st.container()
    with container:
        youtube_url = st.text_input('Or enter your Youtube URL')
    if youtube_url:
        with st.spinner('Mashing your video in vectors...'):
            loader = YoutubeLoader.from_youtube_url(youtube_url)
            documents = loader.load()
            text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200)
            chunks = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
            embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
            vector_store = Chroma.from_documents(chunks, embeddings)
            st.session_state["retriever"] = vector_store.as_retriever()
        st.write("Video mashed!  Click on Ask Questions!")


def ask_questions():
    st.title(":football: :green[The Moss Masher] :dog:")
    st.header("Mash your long documents and videos into easy answers!")
    question = st.text_input('Enter your question here!')
    model = st.sidebar.radio("Choose a model:", ("GPT-3.5", "GPT-3.5-16k", "GPT-4"))
    aiTemp = st.sidebar.slider("How Strict (0) to Creative(10) do you want your responses:", min_value=0.0,
                               max_value=2.0, value=0.0, step=0.01)
    if question:
        with st.spinner('Looking for your answer now....'):
            llm = select_model(model, aiTemp)
            crc = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(llm, st.session_state["retriever"])
            if "crc" in st.session_state:
                crc = st.session_state.crc
            if 'history' not in st.session_state:
                st.session_state['history'] = []
            if 'costs' not in st.session_state:
                st.session_state['costs'] = []
            with get_openai_callback() as cb:
                response = crc.invoke({'question': question, 'chat_history': st.session_state['history']})
                st.session_state['costs'].append(cb.total_cost)
            st.session_state['history'].append((question, response))
            st.write(response)
            # for prompts in st.session_state['history']:
            #     st.write("Question: " + prompts[0])
            #     st.write("Answer: " + prompts[1])
            costs = st.session_state.get('costs', [])
            st.sidebar.markdown("## Costs")
            st.sidebar.markdown(f"**Total cost: ${sum(costs):.5f}**")
            for cost in costs:
                st.sidebar.markdown(f"- ${cost:.5f}")
def main():
    try:
        init_page()
        selection = st.sidebar.radio("Go to",
                                     ["Enter OpenAI Key", "Upload A PDF", "Enter YouTube Video", "Ask Questions"])
        if selection == "Enter OpenAI Key":
            create_login_page()
        elif selection == "Upload A PDF":
            create_pdf_page()
        elif selection == "Enter YouTube Video":
            create_youtube_page()
        elif selection == "Ask Questions":
            ask_questions()
    except Exception as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error} on line {error.__traceback__}")
        st.error("Your API key was not valid, please close the site and then try again.")
    finally:
        print("Done")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: e-motta - NOT COOL downvoting for formatting!  Stackoverflow would not let me format the errors correctly as I had "too much code" and not enough text.  You downvote people for asking repeated questions or giving bad answers, not fomrating!

Comment: Honestly, the question does have "too much code" as compared to normal standards for questions asked on stackoverflow. Maybe this is all necessary, but its worth considering how you can condense the question further into smaller chunks specific to the issue at hand.